# How my Scrollrect in UNITY 3d become Responsive for all screen size for android mobile phones only

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

How my Scrollrect in UNITY become Responsive for all screen size for android mobile phones only i already make my scrollrect, buy my problem is the responsive of it for all mobile phone screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Canvas object, and on the CanvasScaler component look for UI Scale Mode. There you select **Scale with Screen Size**, and enter a reference resolution ([here](http://dpi.lv/) you can find some common resolutions for reference). This works for all platforms, not just Android.

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro its work. but i still have another question i wish you can help me here thanks bro

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084362/unity-popup-window-avoid-other-button-with-popup-window-to-be-clickable-when-som

Comment: heres the link bro
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084362/unity-popup-window-avoid-other-button-with-popup-window-to-be-clickable-when-som

Comment: Hi @ArjayGonzagaRomero, if you found my answer helpful I appreciate if you can mark it as accepted. Regarding the new question, I see you were given a link to a correct answer. In addition, I suggest you take a look at Unity's UI tutorials to have a better understanding: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui